# Incomplete xml while convert a ksoap object to xml

Tags: android, xml, ksoap

I want to use the latitude longitude information from the XML output of a web service in an android app.

http://www.webservicex.net/airport.asmx?op=getAirportInformationByAirportCode

When checking the output in a web browser, I get the following:
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
<NewDataSet> <Table> <AirportCode>MSP</AirportCode> <CityOrAirportName>MINNEAPOLIS INTL</CityOrAirportName> <Country>United States</Country> <CountryAbbrviation>US</CountryAbbrviation> <CountryCode>63</CountryCode> <GMTOffset>6</GMTOffset> <RunwayLengthFeet>10000</RunwayLengthFeet> <RunwayElevationFeet>841</RunwayElevationFeet> <LatitudeDegree>44</LatitudeDegree> <LatitudeMinute>54</LatitudeMinute> <LatitudeSecond>0</LatitudeSecond> <LatitudeNpeerS>N</LatitudeNpeerS> <LongitudeDegree>93</LongitudeDegree> <LongitudeMinute>13</LongitudeMinute> <LongitudeSeconds>0</LongitudeSeconds> <LongitudeEperW>W</LongitudeEperW> </Table> <Table> <AirportCode>MSP</AirportCode> <CityOrAirportName>MINNEAPOLIS INTL</CityOrAirportName> <Country>United States</Country> <CountryAbbrviation>US</CountryAbbrviation> <CountryCode>63</CountryCode> <GMTOffset>6</GMTOffset> <RunwayLengthFeet>10000</RunwayLengthFeet> <RunwayElevationFeet>841</RunwayElevationFeet> <LatitudeDegree>44</LatitudeDegree> <LatitudeMinute>54</LatitudeMinute> <LatitudeSecond>0</LatitudeSecond> <LatitudeNpeerS>N</LatitudeNpeerS> <LongitudeDegree>93</LongitudeDegree> <LongitudeMinute>13</LongitudeMinute> <LongitudeSeconds>0</LongitudeSeconds> <LongitudeEperW>W</LongitudeEperW> </Table> </NewDataSet>
</string>
```

I am getting this in the form of a SOAP object in the following code:

```
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/getAirportInformationByAirportCode";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://www.webserviceX.NET";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "getAirportInformationByAirportCode";
private static String URL = "http://www.webservicex.NET/airport.asmx?WSDL";
public String source_textview, destination_textview;

//Initialize soap request + add parameters
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       

//Use this to add parameters
request.addProperty("airportCode",airportCode);

//Declare the version of the SOAP request
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.dotNet = true;

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

try {
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
    //androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
    //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    String result=androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
    Log.d("xml:", "is:" + result);      

} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get the XML as follows:

```
D/xml:(4736): is:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><getAirportInformationByAirportCodeResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET"><getAirportInformationByAirportCodeResult>&lt;NewDataSet /&gt;</getAirportInformationByAirportCodeResult></getAirportInformationByAirportCodeResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Don't worry about the warning message about `style information` - that's just your browser. View source, or use developer tools, Fiddler etc to view the actual xml. Note however that the webservice itself returns an XmlEncoded string - you'll need to decode that before parsing the lats and longs.

Comment: I am not concerned about the warning. I want to use the Soap object I mentioned to extract the lat-long info

Answer (score 0):

The code You entered upthere is not compiling, so its not response for that code you included. Besides of that, the response You shown us is for situation when there is empty parameter airport code. I tried to clean Your code a bit (included below) and it works. Really don't have any idea what did You done wrong before.

```
private  String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/getAirportInformationByAirportCode";
private  String NAMESPACE = "http://www.webserviceX.NET";
private  String METHOD_NAME = "getAirportInformationByAirportCode";
private  String URL = "http://www.webservicex.NET/airport.asmx?WSDL";

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    //Initialize soap request + add parameters
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       

    //Use this to add parameters
    request.addProperty("airportCode","MSP");

    //Declare the version of the SOAP request
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    try {
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        //androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
        //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        String result=androidHttpTransport.responseDump;

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
    return "aaa";
}
```

Now You have to parse XML that is in "getAirportInformationByAirportCodeResult" tag as text.